# How to launch a new process in a new terminal in Linux

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I'm using Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon. I've an `Angular` project and I want to do the following things. All these in a separate terminal:

1. Navigate into project folder and run `code .` so that I can see the code on Visual studio.
2. Navigate into project folder and run `ng serve` to launch my application and keep it running.
3. Navigate into project folder and run `node server.js` to start backend server and keep it running.

   this is very painful as the project location is-

`home/xpert/Documents/social-coder`

and it contains two servers:

1. `social-coder/application` The angular server that runs on `localhost:4200`
2. `social-coder/server/server.js` The backend server that runs on `localhost:3000`

Both the servers need to be constantly running for the application to work.

Navigating again and again with a new terminal is what wasting my time. I decided to write a `shell script` so that I can do all at once with one single click. This is what my **.bashrc** file contains:

```
alias first='gnome-terminal | npm start --prefix Documents/social-coder/application'
alias second='node Documents/social-coder/server/server.js'
alias third='code Documents/social-coder'
```

This is what I've thought. SO, all of the above 3 commands works perfectly If I manually copy-paste them in separate terminals. But again, I have to manually open 3 different terminals and make them run. I'm coming from:

1. [How to write practical shell scripts - Like Geeks](https://likegeeks.com/write-shell-script/)
2. [Run command on another(new) terminal window](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484993/run-command-on-anothernew-terminal-window)
3. [How to Use GNOME Terminal App](https://linuxhint.com/use_gnome_terminal_app/)

`gnome-terminal` opens a new terminal but still runs `npm start` from the same terminal itself.

I admit that I'm a newbie and there are gaps in my knowledge. Please correct me.

Comment: Did you read [man gnome-terminal](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-gnome-terminal/)? Use `-e`. I don't think the `gnome-terminal |` makes sense.

Comment: See guys, I tried this also:
`gnome-terminal -- /bin/bash -c 'npm start --prefix Documents/social-coder/application; node Documents/social-coder/server/server.js; code code Documents/social-coder'

But this will lauch only the first command and ignoring the rest.`

Comment: You can edit your question to provide additional info. `But this will lauch only the first command and ignoring the rest` - The `bash -c 'cmd1; cmd2; cmd3;'` it will run the commands sequentially, one after another. Don't you want 3 separate terminals?

Comment: @KamilCuk. Yes. I want 3 individual terminals

Comment: @KamilCuk. Yes i was wrong about `gnome-terminal |`. Thanks fr the correction. :-)

Answer (score 0):

For now I've created a command using `pipe`. It is working but I'm not sure whether this is the preferred way or not:

`gnome-terminal -- /bin/bash -c 'npm start --prefix Documents/social-coder/application' | gnome-terminal -- /bin/bash -c 'node Documents/social-coder/server/server.js' | gnome-terminal -- /bin/bash -c 'code Documents/social-coder'`

Please feel free to edit this answer.

Comment: The `|` kind of doesn't make sense here. To run a program in the background use `&`.

Comment: Oh. But I would like to see outputs on the console also. Cant run them in background. :-)